# Excel VBA Find number in Cell

Tags: excel, vba

We have the column "following ID", which contains IDs of predecessors in the format "1; 2; 3; 4". Now I want to find the ID inside a specific cell. My problem is, that if I f.e. searching for "1", it also is true when there is a "11, 21, 13, 14, ..." inside the cell. Is there a way to search for the "ID" in "following ID", without getting true when the ID is part of an other ID?

```
For i = 2 To 250
  Dim tmp As String
  tmp = ""
  If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Exit For
  For j = 2 To 250
    If Cells(j, 1) = "" Then
      Exit For
    End If
    If Cells(j, 11) = Cells(i, 1) Then
      If tmp = "" Then
        tmp = Cells(j, 1)
      Else
        tmp = tmp & "; " & Cells(j, 1)
      End If
    End If
 Next j
 Cells(i, 10) = tmp
Next i
```

[Picture of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shJO5.png)

Comment: can you show your code so that we can check what is wrong with it?

Comment: How many of these ; separated numbers can there be in a cell?

Comment: The code you currently have doesn't justify your description. What are you trying to achieve here i.e. which column contains ";" separated IDs and which number you are trying to search? It would be better if you can elaborate more and share the screenshot of your data and the desired output to visualize the requirement more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to do can be described minimally with the following:
 - *Try to search for "1" in the string "1;2;3;4;11;12;13", returning only "1" and not "11", "12", "13".*

This is a way to do it:

- split the string to array by ";"
- search in the array

---

The code would look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputA  As String
    Dim cnt     As Long
    Dim arr     As Variant

    inputA = "1;2;3;4;11;12;13"

    arr = Split(inputA, ";")

    For cnt = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If 1 = arr(cnt) Then
            Debug.Print "Found in position " & cnt
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UDF like below:

```
    Public Function FindID(rngToCheck As Range, strVal As String) As Boolean
        If InStr(1, ";" & Replace(rngToCheck.Value, " ", "") & ";", ";" & strVal & ";", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then FindID = True
    End Function
```

And then check the cell like below assuming your data is in Cell A2:

```
     =FindID(A2,"1")
```